# Pomodoro Software for OSX?

Tags: macos, software-rec, productivity

I have recently been using the [Pomodoro Technique](http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/) to help me accomplish tasks. I currently do it using timer on my phone. I was wondering if there is any software that runs on OSX Lion that can place a Pomodoro countdown clock in the task bar and possibly provide other features related to the Pomodoro technique.

Comment: http://osx.iusethis.com/search?q=pomodoro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the highest rated option there which is called [Pomodoro](http://pomodoro.ugolandini.com/). It's open source, so I compiled from source. So far it seems to be what I wanted. It has nifty integration with lots of other software and I can see myself using that functionality in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A simple pomodoro timer can be implemented with a few lines of code. The advantage is that you don't need to install any third-party software and you can customize it as you imagine.

Here is a simple script [link](https://gist.github.com/ManashRaja/3b72e7c79ded43f87280fd6e6baa56de).
Download the `pomodoro.sh` file from the above link and execute the following to run it:
`$ bash pomodoro.sh`

It will give you 25-minute sections for your tasks and 5-minutes of breaks in between. Though you can change the time as you like in the script.

I can help you customize if you want. Hope it help.